# What to call a date when a scheduled activity can't be cancelled?

Tags: word-request

Is a date (5/5/2020 or whatever) "occupied", "busy", or else when there's some scheduled activity that can't be cancelled?

I mean, you can say 'I'm busy on Friday' or something, but I need to specifically characterize a date with some adjective to convey that a new event can't be held on the same day. What are natural ways to say that?

Suppose, here's a sentence, "The date is [word] with holding an election". What word would you use?

Comment: 'Booked' might work; is this a professional or personal context?

Comment: I considered 'booked' but for me, it has strong associations with hotels and restaurants. So you assert that it still would be okay?

Comment: Well, that's why I'm asking about the context.  Is this a business thing (making appointments), or is it in personal life (e.g. going to a show, can't go visiting)?

Comment: It's not about hotels or restaurants, this I can tell you

Comment: Without more context than that, it's hard to say for sure.  Booked is fine for most professional contexts, not just hotels and restaurants, but it would sound odd in most personal contexts.  In personal contexts, nothing specific comes to mind; we often use generic negatives, e.g. "The 5th is no good," "The 5th won't work."

Comment: Suppose, here's a sentence, "The date is [word] with holding an election". What word would you use?

Comment: Do you need an adjective, specifically, or would a verb do?  You could probably use **consumed by** in this context; e.g. "The 5th will be entirely consumed by holding an election; we won't be able to do anything else of note."

Comment: I, frankly, don't think this is a good idea. Never heard of "consuming a date"

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any clarifications you make, not the comments. And please include your example sentence in the post from the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the comments under the question that *booked* would normally be fine in almost any context. I will add it as a possibility, although it doesn't seem to be what you're looking for.

In a comment, you also say:

> Suppose, here's a sentence, "The date is [word] with holding an election". What word would you use?

As you want to make the date the subject of the sentence, rather than you yourself, then you could say any of these:

> The date is **booked** by an election.
>   The date is **unavailable** due to an election.
>   The date is **taken** by an election.

Comment: The Lexico entry doesn't seem to support 'book' in this case (https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/book). And are you sure that 'by' should be used, not 'with'? Election can't book anything

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Yes, I'm sure this is correct.

Comment: That's what the Longman dictionary says,"By is used, especially after passive verbs, to say who or what does something:
The article was written by a university professor.
She was hit by a truck.
• With is used after verbs that describe a state rather than an action:
The books were covered with dust.
Her house is always filled with music." Note the last example, 'filled WITH music', not 'BY music'. It's similar

Comment: The date would be booked *for* an election.

Comment: @user34258 As with many phrases that use prepositions, more than one preposition is possible. Which preposition is used is a matter of style and personal preference.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica So you insist that 'by' is correct and 'with' is incorrect, don't you? How do you explain the passage from the Longman dictionary then?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev No, not at all. Both *by* and *with* are fine. As is *for*, as mentioned in another comment above. As I said there, it's a matter of preference. There is no single preposition that must be used to the exclusion of all others.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly, here, the *context* makes a lot of difference. Depending on the context, you may use the words. As the discussion went, *book* for hotels etc.; *busy* for other engagement; *unavailable* in most of the contexts. At times, even *taken* works. Quite **informally**, *gone* may also serve the purpose. I had also heard *listed out* in some cases.

So, *context* is the key!

For your example: The date is [unavailable] due to an election".

Comment: Is there anything else I can use with the sentence I suggested apart from 'unavailable'? I want something with 'with' or 'by'

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev if you want *by/with,* I'm afraid, it'd not look natural. And, your question is about **what looks natural!**